# javascript not working with printwriter in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, printwriter

Hi I am creating a webpage which is developed from a servlet using printwriter , I am appending HTML,css and js , but the javascript functions are not working , is this beacause of any syntax error or is it not supported js inside java?

my code

```
String htmlHeader = null;
        htmlHeader = "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>"
                + title
                +"</TITLE>"
                +"<link rel=stylesheet href=/resources/css/jquery-ui.css>"
                +"<script src=//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js></script>"
                +"<script src=//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js></script>"
                +"<style type=text/css>"
                +"body "
                +"{background-image: url(resources/img/timer_page_new.png);"
                +"-moz-background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover;"
                +"background-size: cover;background-position: top center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;"
                +"background-attachment: fixed;}"
                +"#sel.ui-selecting { background: '#FECA40'; }"
                +"#sel.ui-selected { background: '#F39814'; color: '#7e7d79'; }"
                +"#sel { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }"
                +"#sel li { margin: 6px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 28px; }</style>"

                +"<script type=text/javascript>"
                +"function init(){"
                +"var ol = document.getElementById('selectable');"
                +" var macId ="+macId+" ;"
                + "var entry = document.createElement('li');"
                +"entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(macId));"
                +"ol.appendChild(entry);"
                +"ol.addEventListener('click', function(e) {"
                +"if (e.target.tagName === 'LI'){"
                +"alert(e.target.id);"
                +"}" 
                +"});"
                +"}"
                +"setTimeout(function () {"
                +" location.reload();"
                +" }, 20 * 1000);"
                +"</script>"
                +"</HEAD><BODY onload=init("+macId+","+tHr+","+tMin+")><div align=center>";
        return htmlHeader;
```

js file with function init()

```
function init(macId,tHr,tMin){

              var sTempTableRow='<tr><td width=150px><div align=center><font size=4 color=white face=verdana>'+macId+'</font></div></td>'
              +'<td width=150px><div align=center><font size=4 color=white face=verdana>'+tHr+'</font></div></td></tr>'
              +'<td width=150px><div align=center><font size=4 color=white face=verdana>'+tMin+'</font></div></td>';
              $('#timerTable').append(sTempTableRow);
          }
```

part of html

```
<BODY onload=init("+macId+","+tHr+","+tMin+")>
```

Comment: Why do you not use JSP? It makes it much more easier to write correct JavaScript. Best combination is to use Spring WebMVC with JSPs

Comment: you cannot do that directly.

Comment: @Schrieveslaach using Spring WebMVC is opinion based. But @ James why don't you use jsp to code your html page?

Comment: @Naman, you are write. I should have written a good combination. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to code your javascript in your html file that I would say you can use JSP instead of Servlet.

But if you want to use servlet then you can move your `css` and `javascript` part in separate `.css` and `.js` files respectively and just include those files using your `PrintWriter`. And whatever dynamic fields you want to pass to javascript that you can pass as **parameters** to your javascript function (like `function init(macId) {`).

Comment: if I am using jsp , if I need to update my listview and table should I dynamically build them ? or is there any way to pass those dynamic fields to html ?

Comment: JSP is used for dynamically building html. And you can include your java code or method calls to fetch data from its source say database inside JSP.

Comment: Hi , could you give a sample function with parameter in body onload , the function should create a new row dynamically with the passing parameter in the table , I have tried but it is not showing any stuff :(

Comment: Show me what you have tried? We will try to resolve the problem in your code.

Comment: Why are using init function to create table row on body load? You can directly create table row in your jsp file.

Comment: I have moved css and js part to corresponding files , css is reading well but js is not..

Comment: Im not using jsp , I am using servlets , I have included the css and js files

Comment: I have 2 question. **1,** What is the significance of your javascript function, why don't you directly create that html code in your servlet instead of depend on javascript function. **2.** Where have you kept your js and css file in your project?

Comment: Hey I have solved my issue , I dont need a seperate js file , you are right :) sorry my mistake , Now my js file is reading , thanks for the assistance thumps up!